# Passing arguments to Node.js program

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, yargs

I'm trying to pass 2 mandatory arguments for a Node.js program I'm creating.

I'm using `Yargs` to do it like this:

```
const yarg = require("yargs")
.usage("hi")
.options("m", {demandOption: true})
.options("m2", {demandOption: true})
.argv;
```

This works fine with a slight issue. I want to activate the script like this:

> node index.js -m val -m2 val2

It doesn't work and I get an error saying m2 is missing. Only when I add another `-` before m2 it works, meaning I have to do it like this:

> node index.js -m val1 --m2 val2

Is there a way to make it accept the args like I wanted to in the first place?

Comment: You can have it how you wanted in the first place if you dont use yargs - process command line arguments by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're asking for with yargs, and arguably you shouldn't. It's easy to see why you can't by looking at what [yargs-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs-parser) (the module yargs uses to parse your arguments) returns for the different argument styles you mentioned:

```js
console.log(yargsParser(['-m', 'A']));
console.log(yargsParser(['-m2', 'B']));
console.log(yargsParser(['--m2', 'C']));
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/yargs-parser@11.1.1"></script>
```

As you can see:

1. `-m A` is parsed as option `m` with value `A`.
2. `-m2 B` is parsed as option `m` with value `2` and, separately, array parameter `B`.
3. `--m2 C` is parsed as option `m2` with value `C`.

There is not a way to make the parser behave differently. This is with good reason: Most command line tools (Windows notwithstanding) behave this way.

By decades-old convention, "long" options use two dashes followed by a human-readable name, like `--max-count`. "Short" options, which are often aliases for long ones, use a single dash followed by a single character, like `-m`, and—this is the crucial bit—if the option takes a value, the space between the option and the value can be omitted. This is why when yargs sees `-m2`, it assumes `2` is the value for the `m` option.

If you want to use yargs (and not confuse command line-savvy users) you'll you need to change your options to either 1. `--m` and `--m2` or, 2. `-m` and (for example) `-n`.

Comment: 1) is there a possibility to make the parser not omit the space between the name and value?  2) How can I make the user put 2 dashes before the first parameter? I just defined m and it takes a single dash automatically...

Comment: This might be helpful for you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words

Comment: @Jordan Running so do you have an answer?